# Java.xml.validation.Schema from wsdl

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl, schema, java-metro-framework

So I have a web service in NetBeans 8.1, for which I've written the wsdl with embedded XSD (and an external ref also).
Now I need to be able call the SOAP service on other instances of the application:
i.e. have instance X call a method on instance Y, as a secondary goal of the application.
I don't like to use NetBeans automatic SOAP client wizards, as I would be pointing to the very service which I'm building - it would potentially be a chicken and the egg type of thing during building. Secondly, I already have all the required JAXB types used by the web service, so it should be easy to construct a client right?

Well my trouble starts when I want to use JAXB to marshal my request object into a `javax.xml.soap.SOAPBodyElement` (my current strategy is to use SAAJ for the client part), but how to add a Schema to the marshaller? the schema is embedded in the wsdl, and I can't figure out how to reference it.
I figured that I could split out the schema part into a separate XSD file, but I'm missing an annotation option for `@WebService`, where I can provide an XSD file, just like I can provide a wsdl file (currently the 'wsdlLocation' points to both wsdl & xsd as it is embedded).

I guess I may have to live with not doing XSD validation on the client side(it is enabled server-side), as it seems tricky to get a Schema object from the wsdl - is that possible somehow?

Comment: I never solved this, but rather chose to use a dedicated interface for the specific use case, which was offloading sub-tasks to other instances of the application (this was pre-cloud/docker world). Instead i simply send the objects as application/x-java-serialized-object, have them processed, and returned to me. The overall task is also available via the soap ws, but less efficient though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the .wsdl as an InputStream and transform it to a DOMResult. You can then get the "schema" node from the DOMResult and turn it into a DOMSource. With that, you can make a Schema object using the Source[] constructor.

I haven't got it to work myself, I had too many imports and it became hell to manage the namespaces. The only code I found on this was in "SOA Using Java Web Services" by Mark Hansen, chapter 7.5.1: Validation. I don't think I can put that code here, but all the code you should need for this use case is in there.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I'll accept the answer, but in the meantime I've gone a different route - as it is only internal calls, I just implemented a servlet to receive ObjectStreams - it performs a lot better, and performance turned out to be crucial here.